# error(1,-1005) when streaming mp3 in media player android

Tags: android, http, streaming, media-player, mp3

i'm developping player in android and i have this error when reloading url from network.
I'm using mediaplayer within Service.
What is error(1,-1005) in media player android?
Thanks

Comment: @ShashankAgarwal why?!! The question is clear

Comment: @mok because without some code, we cannot understand what the user has already tried, and where he/she is doing wrong. That's explained better in the [Stackoverflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Code `-1005` means `ERROR_CONNECTION_LOST`. See [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/kitkat-release/include/media/stagefright/MediaErrors.h).